# firewalld - No such file or directory

Tags: iptables, firewalld, nftables

After upgrading from Ubuntu 20.04 to 20.10 I want to finally get started with firewalld instead of the old manual iptables approach, but all I get from the service is the following, which also breaks any network integration with Docker:

```
Feb 13 13:28:20 myhost firewalld[36390]: ERROR: 'python-nftables' failed: internal:0:0-0: Error: Could not process rule: No such file or directory
```

That error message is not really helpful, since it doesn't say "what" can not be found.

I also tried to execute the JSON blob (from `journalctl --unit firewalld --no-pager`) using the `nft` command directly, but that just gives the same error message, actually mutliple times. So the error message is the one coming from `libnftables1`.

Comment: You may want to read the info on this link. https://net2.com/ubuntu-20-10-comes-with-nftables-as-firewall/

Comment: Yes, that is what made me start getting into firewalld instead of ufw (which I haven't used before anyway - was plain iptables/persistent). But the info on that link doesn't help me solve the issue.

Comment: Well it says firewalld is not part of Ubuntu 20.10 hence that is the missing file in your error message.

Comment: I have all the tools installed (as firewalld package depends on python3-nftables, which in turn depends on libnftables1), I also have installed the nft CLI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reviewing a bit of Python code [here](https://github.com/firewalld/firewalld/blob/v0.9.1/src/firewall/core/nftables.py#L361) and [here](https://git.netfilter.org/nftables/tree/py/nftables.py?h=v0.9.6#n435) it became clear that I need to disassemble the big JSON blob and see which instructions exactly fail, which lead me to the following (after storing the JSON blob into `~/nftables.json`):

```bsh
jq '.nftables | length' ~/nftables.json
```

...to get the number of entries (225 in my case) and then:

```bsh
for i in $(seq 1 224); do \
    jq --argjson index "$i" '{"nftables": [.nftables[0], .nftables[$index]]}' ~/nftables.json | tee nft.json; \
    sudo nft --json --file nft.json || break; \
done
```

...which failed just for the first entry:

```json
{
  "nftables": [
    {
      "metainfo": {
        "json_schema_version": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "add": {
        "chain": {
          "family": "inet",
          "table": "firewalld",
          "name": "raw_PREROUTING",
          "type": "filter",
          "hook": "prerouting",
          "prio": -290
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
internal:0:0-0: Error: No such file or directory
```

As this was just adding a chain, the only thing that could be wrong here is a missing table, which was confirmed by:

```bsh
$ sudo nft list tables
table bridge filter
table bridge nat
```

...so we need to add it:

```bsh
sudo nft add table inet firewalld
```

After some more similar failures, I ended up with just the following tables being added manually:

```
table inet firewalld
table ip firewalld
table ip6 firewalld
```